# Java Concurrency in Practice: 3.5.4 Effectively immutable objects: Do we need Thread-Safe Collection containers for effectively immutable objects

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, immutability

Section 3.5.4 discusses about effectively immutable objects, that is, once an object is safely and fully constructed, its state would not be changed by any code of any code-path.

Sir Goetz has given an example:

> For example, `Date` is mutable, but if you use it as if it were
>   immutable you may be able to eliminate the locking that would
>   otherwise be required when shared[sharing] a Date across threads.
>   Suppose you want to maintain a Map storing the last login time of each
>   user:
>
> ```
> public Map<String, Date> lastLogin = 
> Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<String, Date>());
> ```
>
> If the `Date` values are not modified after they are placed in the
>   `Map`, then the synchronization in the `synchronizedMap`
>   implementation is sufficient to publish the `Date` values safely, and
>   no additional synchronization is needed when accessing them.

The point that I am not able to understand is that why do we want to use `synchronizedMap` and bear the extra overhead of its internal lockings when we could have simply used unsafe `Map`, because after all we would be placing effectively immutable `Date` objects in it - which means, that once properly and fully constructed and published, it would not be mutated anymore. And so even if the `Map` itself be unsafe, there would be just no code in any of the code-paths which could concurrently mutate any `Date` instance while other thread(s) has retrieved it from the Unsafe `Map`.

To sum up, the very premise of effectively immutable objects does not necessitate need of any Thread-safe containers since we should just not have any mutator code in any code-path for effectively immutable objects.

Comment: Yes, `Date` itself is immutable. But you are calling map.put() from multiple threads. And `map` is not immutable. You are *adding* it it.

Comment: Without synchronisation, one thread reading the map would not be guaranteed to see the changes made by another thread.

Comment: @fukanchik:  `Date` isn't immutable.  What are you talking about?

Comment: @Makoto read the question: `Date is mutable, but if you use it as if it were immutable you may be able to eliminate the locking`

Comment: @fukanchik:  The main thing I'd like to stress here is that you don't want to call something immutable when it isn't. `Date` is infamously immutable; the phrasing you probably wanted to use was "effectively immutable".

Comment: @assylias Got your point. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use an `un-synchronized` `mutable map` and share it across `threads` then you will have two `thread-safety` issues :`visibility` and `atomicity`. `Thread-1` wont know if `Thread-2` has removed a `Map-Entry` or it replaced its value by a new `Date` object.

```
// not atmoic and doesn't guarantee visiblity
if(map.contains(key)){
 map.put(key,newDate); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The key phrase from the original text is, "fully constructed and published."  "Published", in particular refers to making an object created by one thread visible to other threads, and when the object is not *truly* immutable, then it must be done *safely* (Google "Java safe publication").

Without synchronization, Java does not guarantee that updates to variables made by one thread will be seen by other threads or, in what order the updates will be seen.

In most computer architectures, providing a consistent view of shared memory to all of the threads is relatively expensive.  By not requiring the threads to have a consistent view except when explicitly synchronizing, Java allows the threads to get a consistent view when it is needed, or to get the best performance possible when it is not needed.

Also, All of the above ignores the very real possibility that the program might need to synchronize accesses to the Map for *other* reasons (e.g., to prevent simultaneous updates from corrupting the Map itself.)

Comment: I see your point especially in the last passage. Even though the Date objects are used as effectively immutable in this particular example, the containers that would contain these Date objects is not thread-safe. This might lead to visibility, dirty reads and all sorts of inconsistencies in an concurrent environment.